# Generate model classes from the database

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, spring-boot, jpa

I have created a Spring Boot project and would like to communicate with an SQL Server 2017 database running on a Docker Container.

What is the quickest way to generate code for model classes in Eclipse (Oxygen.2 Release 4.7.2)?

I put my `pom.xml` and `application.properties` here if it helps.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.blahblahblah</groupId>
    <artifactId>querytofile</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>querytofile</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=myDB
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=BLAHBLAHBLAH
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

**Update: Snapshot from Marketplace**

[image]

Comment: You can use JPA Tool to generate the entities from the db tables.

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks006.htm

Comment: I don't get the "JPA Tools" option when I right-click on my project in Project Explorer.

Comment: you need to install Plugin from eclipse marketplace.

Comment: I cannot seem to find a plugin with the name *JPA Tools* in the marketplace.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

open eclipse IDE :

Go to > help > eclipse marketplace > search JPA > select g9 Database Import as below.

[image: plugin]

restart eclipse IDE.

Right click on project > import > search for Import Database Model as below.

[image: Import DB]

provide required fields and generate the entities.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I click on "Install" on g9 Database Import it does not show up on my Marketplace Window. When I search for JPA in the marketplace, I get other options. g9 does not appear until I click on "Browse for more solutions".

Comment: but then it appear or what?

Comment: @rick I search for "JPA" in the marketplace, it does not show up in the initial results. So I scroll all the way down and click on "click for more solutions". This opens a tab in the Eclipse web browser in which I see the g9 Database Import in the search results. So I click on "Install". The marketplace is opened with no g9 in the results. This is slightly confusing.

Comment: which IDE version you are using ?

Comment: @rick Oxygen.2 Release 4.7.2

Comment: Open market place in IDE  > go to https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/g9-database-import > drag "Install" button to market place popup window.

Comment: @NeerajBenjwal I have tried that. I drag the button to Eclipse, the marketplace is opened. But no g9 is shown.

Comment: Can you please share the window screenshot after drag ?

Comment: @Disasterkid After drag and drop what it is showing ?

Comment: @NeerajBenjwal please check the update part of the question.

Comment: @NeerajBenjwal I think there's something wrong with my Eclipse. I have it on Mac OS. Could it be that some libraries are exclusive to some countries? Because when I test other libraries, they show up in the Marketplace. But not this one. Some compatibility issue maybe?